# What's the best way to count the number of references based on conditions in both "home" and "away" tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm working on a project, and using Knex for it, (though if you give me raw SQL I'm pretty sure I can convert that as well.)

So, here's the sitch.

I have tables 'group' and 'user_group'.

```
table 'group' 
  id: integer
  name: string
  is_public: boolean
table 'user_group'
  group_id: ref(group.id)
  user_id: ref(user.id) // don't need user table info for this
  role: string
```

What I'd like to do is get a list of all groups

- where is_public is TRUE
- returning the group.name and group.id
- and a count of how many members the group has.
- sorted from most members to least

So an output would look like this:

```
[
  {name: "Clowns", memberCount: 20, id: 3},
  {name: "Puppets", memberCount: 12, id: 36},
  {name: "Jugglers", memberCount: 5, id: 12},
  ...
]
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
  SELECT COUNT('*') AS memberCount, group.name AS name, group.id AS id
  FROM group
  INNER_JOIN user_group on group.id = user_group.group_id
  WHERE group.is_public = true
  AND WHERE user_group.role = "MEMBER"
  ORDER BY memberCount ASC`
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: No `GROUP BY` needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as:

```
SELECT g.name, g.id, COUNT(ug.role) AS memberCount
FROM group g LEFT JOIN
     user_group ug
     ON ug.group_id = g.id AND
        ug.role = 'MEMBER'
WHERE g.is_public
GROUP BY g.name, g.id
ORDER BY memberCount DESC;
```

How is this structured?  First, this is using a `LEFT JOIN` because you want *all* groups, presumably even those with no members.  Because of the `LEFT JOIN`, the condition on the role is in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Some other notes:

- Use single quotes for string and date constants.  This is the SQL standards.
- Aggregate by all the keys in the `SELECT`.
- To get results from highest to lowest, use a `DESC` `ORDER BY`.
- There is no need to specify `= true` for a boolean, although there is no issue either.

Comment: Thanks.  An inner join would work here because the way the app is structured, there would never be a group with 0 members.

I'm a little confused by "group g" and "user_group ug" but I guess that's just how SQL allows you to use variables.  Good to know.

Comment: @BrianBoyko . . . Those are called "table aliases", not "variables".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS-SQL then below query will help you.
Aggregate functions are often used with the GROUP BY clause of the SELECT statement.So you need to use group by clause.

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS memberCount, group.name AS name, group.id AS id
       FROM group
 INNER_JOIN user_group on group.id = user_group.group_id
       WHERE group.is_public = 1
```

----if column is bit datatype then put 1 for

true.

```
       AND WHERE user_group.role = 'MEMBER'
  group by group.name,group.id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The table `user_group` must be grouped like this:

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(user_id) AS memberCount
FROM user_group
WHERE role = 'MEMBER'
GROUP BY group_id
```

By this grouping you can get the number of users belonging in each group. 
Now the above query must be joined to the `group` table:

```
SELECT
  ug.memberCount, g.name, g.id
FROM group AS g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT group_id, COUNT(user_id) AS memberCount
    FROM user_group
    WHERE role = 'MEMBER' 
    GROUP BY group_id
) AS ug
ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE g.is_public = TRUE
ORDER BY ug.memberCount DESC, g.name
```

The above query will return only the groups that have at least 1 member. 
If you also want all the other groups with 0 members you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(ug.memberCount,  0) AS memberCount, g.name, g.id
FROM group AS g
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT group_id, COUNT(user_id) AS memberCount
    FROM user_group
    WHERE role = 'MEMBER' 
    GROUP BY group_id
) AS ug
ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE g.is_public = TRUE
ORDER BY ug.memberCount DESC, g.name
```